# Convert varchar to DateTime not working on table but works on individual values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column `ImportDate` of datatype `varchar(100)`.

I want to convert its values from `varchar` to `Datetime` and for that I have used this query:

```
select 
    convert(datetime, ImportDate) 
from ImportHistory
```

But it throws an exception with message

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But when I individually select each value and run the statement it works fine. For example the below query works perfectly, and so do all the values in the table

```
select convert(Datetime, '1826-07-04 18:20:00')
```

There are no null values in that table and below are the values:

```
1826-07-04 18:20:00
1826-07-04 18:20:00
1917-11-08 11:11:00
2003-07-16 16:02:00
1984-06-08 00:00:00
2004-06-05 00:00:00
1826-07-04 18:20:00
1826-07-04 18:20:00
1917-11-08 11:11:00
2003-07-16 16:02:00
1984-06-08 00:00:00
2004-06-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are those really the only values in the table?

Comment: You have some value in your table that is unable to be cast as a datetime. If at all possible you should not store dates as strings for this very reason (and a host of other issues).

Comment: You could try altering your query to convert only part of the table (do you have sequential IDs?) and try to narrow down where the problem row(s) are.

Comment: This would likely shed some light on at least one offending value. What does this return? select MIN(ImportDate), MAX(ImportDate) from ImportHistory

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` means you have something other than a recognizable date in that column somewhere..

Comment: I tried selecting each value convert,but not even single one worked . But the MIN(ImportDate), MAX(ImportDate) is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2012+, use [`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) or [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) in this kind of scenario:

```
DECLARE @ImportHistory TABLE (ImportDate VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @ImportHistory
VALUES
('1826-07-04 18:20:00'),
('1826-07-04 18:20:00'),
('1917-11-08 11:11:00'),
('2003-07-16 16:02:00'),
('1984-06-08 00:00:00'),
('2004-06-05 00:00:00'),
('1826-07-04 18:20:00'),
('1826-07-04 18:20:00'),
('1917-11-08 11:11:00'),
('Invalid!'),
('2003-07-16 16:02:00'),
('1984-06-08 00:00:00'),
('2004-06-05 00:00:00')

SELECT
    ImportDate, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ImportDate) as dt
FROM @ImportHistory
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ImportDate) IS NULL
-- output: Invalid!, NULL
```

To find the invalid value.  If you want invalid values to be converted to NULL, you can remove the `WHERE` clause and just use `TRY_PARSE` in place of `CONVERT`.

The dates you've listed are all valid, but it's very likely in your actual table you have at least one invalid date - or at least not one that can be parsed as is (extra space, month/day stored in different culture format, etc.).

If you must keep your column as a `VARCHAR` for some unknown reason and you want to make sure that applications don't insert unparsable dates into it, you could add a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE ImportHistory 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ImportDate 
   CHECK(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ImportDate) IS NOT NULL)
```

If you don't have SQL Server 2012+, you could try making a cursor to find the invalid data:

```
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME;

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE test_cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Importdate FROM @ImportHistory

    OPEN test_cursor1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor1 INTO @dt
        SET @dt2 = CONVERT(datetime, @dt)
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @dt
END CATCH
-- output: Invalid!
```

Comment: Thanks Dan Field !! I am suing SQL Server 2008 and I executed the Cursor to find the invalid data and  it failed on first value itself .

Comment: No problem.  If this helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer so other users will be able to more easily find it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved the issue.

Select Convert(Datetime, LTRIM ( RTRIM ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( ImportDate, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '') ) )) from ImportHistory

Thank you All !!